# rails: change image on click when image url is dynamic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I use Rails 4 and have a page with one large image and 6 thumbnails.
When a user clicks on one of the thumbnails then the large image should change to the one of the clicked thumbnails.

in my app/views/products/show.html.erb:

```
   <div class="product-teaser-column">
     <%= image_tag product_image_url(@product, type: :three_quarter, color: colors.first), itemprop: "image", class: 'teaser' %>
   </div>        

   <div class="product-thumbnail-column">
      <ul class="product-thumbnails" class "thumbnails inline">
        <% type_map.except(:thumb, :reversiblefront).each_with_index do |type, index| %>
        <li class='thumbnail'>
      <%= image_tag product_image_url(@product, type: type, color: colors.first), itemprop: "image", class: 'thumbnail' %>
        </li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

I used to have image files in app/assets/images and implemented this feature with jQuery.
In app/assets/javascripts/application.js:

```
// change teaserimage on thumbnail-click
$(function() {
  var images = [
    "/assets/Nile_1_16_0119.jpg", "/assets/Nile_1_16_0095.jpg",
    "/assets/Nile_1_16_0131.jpg", "/assets/Nile_1_16_0144.jpg",
    "/assets/thumb_midnight.jpg", "/assets/back_midnight.jpg"
  ];

  $(".thumbnail").click(function() {
    var index = $(this).parent().index();
    $('img.teaser').attr('src', images[index]);
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
  });
});
```

How can I achieve that when the image Urls are dynamic?

app/helpers/products_helpers.rb:

```
module ProductsHelper
  def product_image_url(product, type:, color:)
    source = URI.escape "#{product_image_base_url}/#{collection_folder(product)}/"\
                        "#{product_number(product)}_#{product_type(type)}"\
                        "_#{format_color_name(color.name)}.jpg"
    image_exist?(source, product) ? source : false
  end

  def product_image_base_url
    ENV['PRODUCT_IMAGE_BASE_URL']
  end

  def product_number(product)
    product.number.strip.upcase
  end

  def product_type(type)
    type_map.fetch(type)
  end

  def type_map
    @type_map ||= {
      full: "01",
      three_quarter: "02",
      medium: "03",
      close_up: "04",
      front: :front,
      back: :back,
      thumb: :thumb,
      reversiblefront: :reversiblefront
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: Hey, you can get image src from thumbnail click event and replace main image src from jquery.

Comment: Thanks Hardik, that's right, it's much easier than i thought!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Hardik suggested i could just replace in my js-code the images array with the thumbnail image urls:

```
var productImages = $("img.thumbnail").map(function() {
    return this.src;
}).get();
```

I had misleadingly something with precompiled assets in mind when i was asking. Thanks Hardik for guiding me to the right direction!